# NFSv3 works but not NFSv4 on Armbian

Tags: linux, nfs

I am trying to mount a NFS share from a NAS, it work flawlessly on my pc (Arch) but on my odroid (Armbian), only NFSv3 works, not NFSv4.

```
$ sudo mount.nfs -vvv 10.10.0.131:/volume1/Owncloud data rw
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Jun  1 12:01:19 2016
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=10.10.0.131,clientaddr=10.10.0.130'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=10.10.0.131'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.10.0.131 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 10.10.0.131 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 42889
```

Maybe a package is missing ? I have installed nfs-common, I think that's all I need.

The other thing is that the owner of the mounted directory is set to 999, I don't know what user it is. It weird because on my pc it's just root or "me" if I add the 'user' option, and there is no user with uid 999 on my NAS ...

Comment: Generally, the owner of a mounted NFS directory is chosen by the server or the client ?